# Android list preferred left padding value and hide textview in array adapter

Tags: android

Hi does anyway know the value for the following attributes:

```
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
```

`android:layout_marginLeft="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"`

I've tried looking at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#listPreferredItemPaddingLeft

but found nothing useful.

I also looked at the attrs.xml file but it just defines it as follows:

```
<!-- The preferred padding along the left edge of list items. -->
<attr name="listPreferredItemPaddingLeft" format="dimension" />

<!-- The preferred padding along the right edge of list items. -->
<attr name="listPreferredItemPaddingRight" format="dimension" />
```

One last thing, if I have an array adapter for a double item list how can I make the second line disappear if it is blank? I tried changing the visibility of the textview to `View.Gone`, but the second row is still taking up space.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hi does anyway know the value for the following attributes:

Those attributes first appeared starting with `ICS`(API level 14) and you can find them in the `themes.xml` file for the `ICS` platform. Those attributes are defined like this:

```
    <item name="listPreferredItemPaddingLeft">6dip</item>
    <item name="listPreferredItemPaddingRight">6dip</item>
```

> One last thing, if I have an array adapter for a double item list how
>   can I make the second line disappear if it is blank? I tried changing
>   the visibility of the textview to View.Gone, but the second row is
>   still taking up space.

To answer this you would need to post the layout file for the list's row and also the code you use for your custom adapter(?!).

Comment: Thanks, I needing the values for compatibility with older API levels. Here is the adapter class:
http://pastebin.com/sVW0Z05w

And here is the xml layout file:
http://pastebin.com/gaL0FnR2

As mentioned before setting the text view to `View.Gone` does not remove the space taken by the textview.

Comment: @user557240 There doesn't seem to be something wrong. Add an `else` clause to the if condition where you set  the visibility: `if (getItem(position).getSuffix().equals("")) {
                        holder.bellType.setVisibility(View.GONE);} else {holder.bellType.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}`. Try to set the height of the `LinearLayout` from the row layout to `match_parent`. Another question is if you tested and you are absolutely sure you get in that `if` condition?

Comment: Yes, the if statement is definitely executed as I added a log comment to check it. I'll try and make the you suggested and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks, I worked it out. It was to do with the minHeight attribute. If I decrease this value the blank line disappears.